# Reasons for using GitHub with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, synchronization, dropbox, project-management

This is not a technical "How do I do it" question, it's more of a "best practices" question. I have done some research and can only find tutorials on HOW to link GitHub and Android Studio.

I am a 'hobbiest' programmer, not professional, but I am trying very hard to follow what the pros do because when I retire from the Army I want to be a software developer and I want to learn what is right, not just 'what works'.

My Question:

I am getting started with Android dev and will be using two different computers; my desktop and my laptop. I thought about using dropbox or even my home file server to keep the project files but then I thought about GitHub (something I have never used before btw).

Is it normal for people to use GitHub to keep the versions on each machine synced up? Do professional programmers do this sort of thing? I would like to be able to sit at either machine and always have access to the same code. I would not be doing version control really (above my level), I have no 'team' (just me messing around) and I don't have any large projects.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? What is the standard in the professional community for this?

I must say, GitHub is initially somewhat intimidating but I have noticed all the pros use it so if I ever want to be a real programmer I might as well figure it out right? I just want to make sure that this is not an off the wall reason to use it.

Thanks!

P.S. I have code that I don't ever want anyone to see. How private is 'private' on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, due to the lack of responses over the last week, I have decided to answer this question myself.

I spoke with some friends who are professional software developers and their general response was "Yes, that is normal". Almost every developer they work with uses Git in some way as a version control system and 90% of them were using GitHub as their primary Git resource. It is very common to store your project files on GitHub even if you are working on a small project that doesn't really need to implement any sort of version control. Many people will still push their projects to GitHub so that they can pull them back down on other devices/machines.

Another comment that they had was that it is important for someone new like me to start building a portfolio of work that I have done. Although I only do programming as a hobby, one day I might want to apply for a position somewhere and having a long history of projects I have worked on loaded up to my GitHub will make it much easier for a potential employer to see my skills, strengths and weaknesses.

On a final note, many software development companies will require you to have a working knowledge of Git, and sometimes, GitHub specifically. Although my current projects are so small and personal that they don't require version control, I should still become familiar with it because if I start working on a larger project for a company, it will almost always implement some sort of version control.

In the end, my final decision was to create a GitHub account and use it for all of my projects that I don't mind the world seeing. I have been using GitHub for the last week for my Android Studio project and, although it was very intimidating at first, I am already getting the hang of it. Not only can I access my project on both of my devices but I can also roll back to previous builds if I screw something up!